# Create duplicates with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This might sound a bit confusing at first. But I have a table with data and I want to create duplicates of all the rows in this table. So, if i do:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
```

it lists all the data in this table. Now, i want to create a copy of all returned results, except for that I want to change data for one column (the date). This will make the new rows unique.

The reason I want to do this is because I want more data in this table since im building statistics out of it for testing purposes. So, if I have this:

```
**Column1   Column2   Column3**
abc       aaa         bbb
abcd      aaaa        bbbb
abcde     aaaaa       bbbbb

The table will now contain:
**Column1   Column2   Column3**
abc       aaa         bbb
abcd      aaaa        bbbb
abcde     aaaaa       bbbbb
abc       aaa         bbb_new
abcd      aaaa        bbbb_new
abcde     aaaaa       bbbbb_new
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
insert into your_table
   select col1, col2, concat(col3, '_new') from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. Altho I wanted up update the current date in the reproduced lines. I used Dateadd for this purpose

Answer (score 3):

Consider making a [Cartesian Join](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CartesianJoin) on your table. This will give you way more data quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO TABLEDUPLICATES
SELECT * FROM the_table


SELECT * FROM TABLEDUPLICATES UNION 
SELECT * FROM the_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is an identity column (ID) you might generate dates (A_Date) like this:

```
insert into the_table (Column1, Column2, A_Date)
select Column1, Column2, A_Date + (rand(ID) - 0.5) * 100
  from the_table
```

Answer (score 2):

To duplicate rows (all columns) you simply could use

```
insert into tblname
select * from tblname
```

to change one column that can be modified to

```
insert into tblname
select column1, column2, 'fixedvalueforcolumn3' from tblname
```

But you need a unique value for column 3, so you have to change 'fixedvalueforcolumn3' to a function that will generate some random (unique) value (date in your case) for column 3

```
insert into tblname
    select column1, column2, generateRandomValue() from tblname
```

Hope that will help you